# protect http request URL

Tags: javascript, php, apache, appcelerator-mobile

i am getting remote JSON value into to my client app as below.

```
var $Xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onerror : function($e) {
            Ti.API.info($e);
        },
        timeout : 5000,
    });

$Xhr.open("GET", "http://***********.json");
    $Xhr.send();
    $Xhr.onload = function() {
        if ($Xhr.status == 200) {
            try {
                Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
            } catch($e) {

                Ti.API.info($e);
            } finally {
                $Xhr = null;
            }
        }
    };
```

My json URL is static. i would like to protect this URL from stranger eyes after creating APK file or publishing for iOS.

Also my server side support PHP. I have thouhgt MD5, SHA etc. but i didn't develop any project about this algortim.

Do you have any suggestion or approach?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean, "protect" ?

Comment: Impossible to protect...

Comment: Proxy it on your server

Comment: how can i proxy? ı couldn't understand.

Comment: @Bartdude it means just app user can access this json.

Answer (score 1):

I would just say that it is not possible for you to "hide" the end point.  Your url will always to visible to the user because otherwise user's browser wouldn't know how to actually post it to your server.

If you meant to only hide the json object, even that is not totally possible. If your javascript knows what the values are then any of your client smart enough to understand javascript will be able to decode your encoded json object. Remember, your javascript has decoded object and a user would have full access to it.  There is no protection against that. At best, you can hide it from everyday user by encoding to with md5 or sha as you put it.

Answer (score 1):

I you wish to restrict access to app user only, you will need to authenticate your users first.

Once they are authenticated, you should generate a hash by concatenating userid (or any user identifying data) and a key that you know (a string will do it), and hashing it using any hashing method, md5 would be enough for that kind of usage I guess, SHA is good anyway.

The next step would be to send this hash with every AJAX request to your server. consider it as an additional data.

Finally, server-side, before treating the request and fetching the data to be sent, just generate a hash the same way you did in your app, using the userid of the requesting user and the same "secret" key you chose. You can now compare both hashes and see if they're identical. If not, then it's probably that someone tried to forge a request from outside your app.

Note that it could be possible for someone authenticated to get his hash (which depends on his ID) and then use it in one of his applications, so it may be a good idea to track the requests server-side in order to check if there's any suspicious usage of your API. You could aswell change your "secret key" regularily (forcing an update of your app though) or define an array with a different key for each day of the year in both your app and server code, so that each individual hashkey will change everyday, recurring each year.